# C++ 2D Struct Array data

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I want to be able to store values from a file into a user defined struct. I want to have columns that hold different types of data such as: a std::string for Character names, a float for Character health and an int for Character experience.

My desired output is to have a 6 by 3 array as shown below

```
 Alice    23.4      3210 
 Xander   45.3      1110
 Bernard  12.9      2024
 Yanni    23.7      1098 
 Craw     50.5      980
 Zack     11.9      1024
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
struct charData
{
    string charName;
    float charHealth;
    int charExp;
};



int main() {
    const int NUM_COLS = 3;
    int NUM_ROWS = 6;
    int charNumber = 0;
    int userInput;
    int loop = 0;
    int i,j;
    string line;

    ifstream myIn;    // Declare read file stream
    myIn.open("party.dat"); // Open file    

    struct charData charArray[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];

    while( !myIn.eof() ) {
        for ( j = 0; j <  NUM_COLS ; j++) {
            for ( i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS ; i++) {
                 myIn >> charArray[i][j].charName;    
                 myIn >> charArray[i][j].charHealth;
                 myIn >> charArray[i][j].charExp;    
            }    
        }    
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

I am also planning on to allow the user to sort the data by each column type.  To sort names alphabetically, sort by health and or experience: I am thinking of using a 2D array. Would this be the best option?

Comment: Why do you need a 2D array and not just an array of `charData`?

Comment: sorry if i say anything weird. i'm a C++ noob. i wanted the information to be kept in a sort of row and columns

Comment: This question fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve]. Please edit your question, so that it includes a [mcve]. It's unlikely that you will get an authoritative answer, until you do this.

Comment: i also plan to to allow the user to sort the data by columns, one option would be to sort names in alphabetical order and the other two would be through int and integer data and i thought a 2D array would be the best option

Comment: This line of code: `struct charData charArray[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];` should be something like this instead: `charData charArray[NUM_ENTRIES];` where `NUM_ENTRIES` would equal the number of lines in your file. Then to print you would only need a single for loop to go through each entry where the index value of the array is a single instance of your struct. A similar for loop would be used for also displaying it to the console.

Comment: thanks guys .. i took all the advice on this page and managed to get my desired out come ... I made that code and ACED that assignment 100%... u guys are GODS AMONG MEN XD.. thank u

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the number of fields in your structure with the number of columns of data.  You show data for only 6 records of 3 fields each.  Try setting NUM_COLS to 1 and see if it works any better for you.

Or, get rid of the second dimension (j) of your array entirely.

Comment: i set the j to one and it worked .. not sure why am trying to wrap my head around it though.  What i had in mind though was to have a 6x3 array. am goning to edit my post for a better explanation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are reading your file as binary or as a text; but within my answer I'm reading from a text file where each field on a line of text is separated by a space character. I will include all files necessary to compile and build a proper working program of what you are looking for. Some of these includes may not be needed but are within my solution for I have larger project that depends on these to properly build.

**stdafx.h**

```
#ifndef STDAFX_H
#define STDAFX_H

#include <Windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

#include <queue>
#include <functional>

#include <algorithm>

// User Application Specific
// #include "ExceptionHandler.h" // Required For My Solution But Isn't Used In Yours

namespace util {

enum ReturnCode {
    RETURN_OK = 0,
    RETURN_ERROR = 1,
}; // ReturnCode

extern const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED;
extern const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED_SHORT;

} // namespace util

#endif // STDAFX_H
```

**stdafx.cpp**

#include "stdafx.h"

```
namespace util {

const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED = static_cast<const unsigned>( -1 );
const unsigned INVALID_UNSIGNED_SHORT = static_cast<const unsigned short>( -1 );

} // namespace util
```

**Utility.h**

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H

namespace util {

class Utility {
public:

    static void pressAnyKeyToQuit();

    static std::string  toUpper(const std::string& str);
    static std::string  toLower(const std::string& str);
    static std::string  trim(const std::string& str, const std::string elementsToTrim = " \t\n\r");

    static unsigned     convertToUnsigned(const std::string& str);
    static int          convertToInt(const std::string& str);
    static float        convertToFloat(const std::string& str);

    static std::vector<std::string> splitString(const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty = true);

private:
    Utility(); // Private - Not A Class Object
    Utility(const Utility& c); // Not Implemented
    Utility& operator=(const Utility& c); // Not Implemented

    template<typename T>
    static bool stringToValue(const std::string& str, T* pValue, unsigned uNumValues);

    template<typename T>
    static T getValue(const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder);

}; // Utility

#include "Utility.inl"

} // namespace util

#endif // UTILITY_H
```

**Utility.inl**

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// stringToValue()
template<typename T>
static bool Utility::stringToValue(const std::string& str, T* pValue, unsigned uNumValues) {
    int numCommas = std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), ',');
    if (numCommas != uNumValues - 1) {
        return false;
    }

    std::size_t remainder;
    pValue[0] = getValue<T>(str, remainder);

    if (uNumValues == 1) {
        if (str.size() != remainder) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::size_t offset = remainder;
        if (str.at(offset) != ',') {
            return false;
        }

        unsigned uLastIdx = uNumValues - 1;
        for (unsigned u = 1; u < uNumValues; ++u) {
            pValue[u] = getValue<T>(str.substr(++offset), remainder);
            offset += remainder;
            if ((u < uLastIdx && str.at(offset) != ',') ||
                (u == uLastIdx && offset != str.size()))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
} // stringToValue
```

**Utility.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utility.h"

namespace util {

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// pressAnyKeyToQuit()
void Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit() {
    std::cout << "Press any key to quit" << std::endl;
    _getch();
} // pressAnyKeyToQuit

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// toUpper()
std::string Utility::toUpper( const std::string& str ) {
    std::string result = str;
    std::transform( str.begin(), str.end(), result.begin(), ::toupper );
    return result;
} // toUpper


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// toLower()
std::string Utility::toLower( const std::string& str ) {
    std::string result = str;
    std::transform( str.begin(), str.end(), result.begin(), ::tolower );
    return result;
} // toLower

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// trim()
// Removes Elements To Trim From Left And Right Side Of The str
std::string Utility::trim( const std::string& str, const std::string elementsToTrim ) {
    std::basic_string<char>::size_type firstIndex = str.find_first_not_of( elementsToTrim );
    if ( firstIndex == std::string::npos ) {
        return std::string(); // Nothing Left
    }

    std::basic_string<char>::size_type lastIndex = str.find_last_not_of( elementsToTrim );
    return str.substr( firstIndex, lastIndex - firstIndex + 1 );
} // trim

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getValue()
template<>
float Utility::getValue( const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder ) {
    return std::stof( str, &remainder );
} // getValue <float>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getValue()
template<>
int Utility::getValue( const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder ) {
    return std::stoi( str, &remainder );
} // getValue <int>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getValue()
template<>
unsigned Utility::getValue( const std::string& str, std::size_t& remainder ) {
    return std::stoul( str, &remainder );
} // getValue <unsigned>

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// convertToUnsigned()
unsigned Utility::convertToUnsigned( const std::string& str ) {
    unsigned u = 0;
    if ( !stringToValue( str, &u, 1 ) ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to unsigned";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return u;
} // convertToUnsigned

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// convertToInt()
int Utility::convertToInt( const std::string& str ) {
    int i = 0;
    if ( !stringToValue( str, &i, 1 ) ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to int";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return i;
} // convertToInt

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// convertToFloat()
float Utility::convertToFloat(const std::string& str) {
    float f = 0;
    if (!stringToValue(str, &f, 1)) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Bad conversion of [" << str << "] to float";
        throw strStream.str();
    }
    return f;
} // convertToFloat

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// splitString()
std::vector<std::string> Utility::splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty ) {
    std::vector<std::string> vResult;
    if ( strDelimiter.empty() ) {
        vResult.push_back( strStringToSplit );
        return vResult;
    }

    std::string::const_iterator itSubStrStart = strStringToSplit.begin(), itSubStrEnd;
    while ( true ) {
        itSubStrEnd = search( itSubStrStart, strStringToSplit.end(), strDelimiter.begin(), strDelimiter.end() );
        std::string strTemp( itSubStrStart, itSubStrEnd );
        if ( keepEmpty || !strTemp.empty() ) {
            vResult.push_back( strTemp );
        }

        if ( itSubStrEnd == strStringToSplit.end() ) {
            break;
        }

        itSubStrStart = itSubStrEnd + strDelimiter.size();
    }

    return vResult;

} // splitString

} // namspace util
```

**CharacterData.h**

```
#ifndef CHARACTER_DATA_H
#define CHARACTER_DATA_H

class CharacterData {
private:
    std::string m_name;
    float       m_health;
    unsigned    m_exp;

public:
    CharacterData();
    CharacterData( const std::string& name, float health, unsigned exp );   

    void setName( const std::string& name );
    void setHealth( float health );
    void setExperience( unsigned exp );

    std::string getName() const;
    float       getHealth() const;
    unsigned    getExperience() const;

private:
    CharacterData( const CharacterData& c ); // Not Implemented
    CharacterData& operator=( const CharacterData& c ); // Not Implemented      

}; // CharacterData

#endif // CHARACTER_DATA_H
```

**CharacterData.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CharacterData.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// CharacterData()
CharacterData::CharacterData() :
m_name( std::string() ),
m_health( 0.0f ),
m_exp( 0 ) {
} // CharacterData

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// CharacterData()
CharacterData::CharacterData( const std::string& name, float health, unsigned exp ) :
m_name( name ),
m_health( health ),
m_exp( exp ) {
} // CharacterData

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setName()
void CharacterData::setName( const std::string& name ) {
    m_name = name;
} // setName

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getName()
std::string CharacterData::getName() const {
    return m_name;
} // getName

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setHealth()
void CharacterData::setHealth( float health ) {
    m_health = health;
} // setHealth

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getHealth()
float CharacterData::getHealth() const {
    return m_health;
} // getHealth

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// setExperience()
void CharacterData::setExperience( unsigned exp ) {
    m_exp = exp;
} // setExperience

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getExperience()
unsigned CharacterData::getExperience() const {
    return m_exp;
} // getExperience
```

**CharacterDatabase.h**

```
#ifndef CHARACTER_DATABASE_H
#define CHARACTER_DATABASE_H

class CharacterData;

class CharacterDatabase {
private:
    std::string m_filename;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>> m_vpCharacters;

public:
    explicit CharacterDatabase( const std::string& filename );
    // ~CharacterDatabase(); // Default Okay

    void displayByOption( unsigned option = 0 );

private:
    CharacterDatabase( const CharacterDatabase& c ); // Not Implemented
    CharacterDatabase& operator=( const CharacterDatabase& c ); // Not Implemented

    void parseFile();
    void display() const;

    static bool sortByName( const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d2);
    static bool sortByHealth( const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d2);
    static bool sortByExperience(const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d2);

}; // CharacterDataase

#endif // CHARACTER_DATABASE_H
```

**CharacterDatabase.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CharacterDatabase.h"

#include "CharacterData.h"
#include "Utility.h"

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// CharacterDatabase()
CharacterDatabase::CharacterDatabase( const std::string& filename ) :
m_filename( filename ) {
    parseFile();
} // CharacterDatabase

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// parseFile()
void CharacterDatabase::parseFile() {
    using namespace util;

    if ( m_filename.empty() ) {
        std::cout << "Missing or invalid filename." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    std::ifstream in;

    // Try To Open File For Reading
    in.open( m_filename.c_str(), std::ios_base::in );
    if ( !in.is_open() ) {
        std::cout << "Can not open file(" << m_filename << ") for reading.";
        return;
    }

    // Read Line By Line And Store Contents Into String & Parse Each Line One At A Time.
    while ( !in.eof() )  {
        std::getline( in, line );
        results = Utility::splitString( line, " " );

        // On Each Pass We Want To Construct A CharacterData Object & Save It Into Our Container
        m_vpCharacters.push_back( std::make_shared<CharacterData>( results[0], Utility::convertToFloat( results[1] ), Utility::convertToUnsigned( results[2] ) ) );
    }

    // Close File Pointer
    in.close();

} // parseFile

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// display()
void CharacterDatabase::display() const {
    for (unsigned u = 0; u < m_vpCharacters.size(); u++) {
        std::cout << m_vpCharacters[u]->getName() << "\t"
            << m_vpCharacters[u]->getHealth() << "\t"
            << m_vpCharacters[u]->getExperience() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
} // display

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// displayByOption() Default 0 = Order In Which File Is Read In, 
// 1 = Sorted By Name, 2 = Sorted By Health, 3 = Sorted By Experience
void CharacterDatabase::displayByOption( unsigned option ) {

    switch ( option ) {
        case 1: { // Sorted By Name
            std::sort( m_vpCharacters.begin(), m_vpCharacters.end(), sortByName );
            display();
            break;
        }
        case 2: { // Sorted By Health
            std::sort( m_vpCharacters.begin(), m_vpCharacters.end(), sortByHealth );
            display();
            break;
        }
        case 3: { // Sorted By Experience
            std::sort( m_vpCharacters.begin(), m_vpCharacters.end(), sortByExperience );
            display();
            break;
        }
        default: { // Unsorted - Order Read In By File
            display();
        }
    }

} // displayByOption

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// sortByName()
bool CharacterDatabase::sortByName( const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d2 ) {
    return d1->getName() < d2->getName();
} // sortByName

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// sortByHealth()
bool CharacterDatabase::sortByHealth( const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d2 ) {
    return d1->getHealth() < d2->getHealth();
} // sortByHealth

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// sortByExperience()
bool CharacterDatabase::sortByExperience( const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<CharacterData>& d2) {
    return d1->getExperience() < d2->getExperience();
} // sortByExperience
```

**characterData.txt**

```
Alice 23.4 3210
Xander 45.3 1110
Bernard 12.9 2024
Yanni 23.7 1098
Craw 50.5 980
Zack 11.9 1024
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utility.h"    
#include "CharacterDatabase.h"

int main() {
    using namespace util;

    CharacterDatabase cd( "characterData.txt" );

    cd.displayByOption();
    cd.displayByOption( 1 );
    cd.displayByOption( 2 );
    cd.displayByOption( 3 );

    Utility::pressAnyKeyToQuit();
    return RETURN_OK;
} // main
```

Just make sure that you are calling the file from the correct path, also when using the Utility::splitString() method make sure the second parameter or the delimiter matches what you have in your stored file. The splitString() method will divide the string from each line of the file every time it sees that character. If you happen to have multiple names such as a first & last name that you want stored to a single string then a little more care needs to be taken.

Comment: lol thanks francis but you have gone way beyond my knowledge of C++ XD .. i appreciate your help very much am gonna come back and look at what you said in depth once my class catches up to some of the concepts

Comment: @William not a problem. Even if you are new and you current understanding is limited, I presented this due to the fact that 70% of the time what is taught in schools is not always adequate in practice. It will take time to learn the syntax of the language and what different aspects of the language are, but the one biggest thing that many places fail to teach is that you main.cpp file or the code in which the executable is generated should be simple, compact and easy to read. The library here is just a single class that is reusable. A struct and a class are very similar with some differences.

Comment: @William (...continued) The best thing you could probably do with what I have presented as long as you are on a windows platform with at least VS2012, 13, or 15 is to create a new empty win32 console solution with pre-compiled headers, add these files into the solution along with the text data file. Make sure the appropriate includes are in the standard include file. Compile it out to make sure everything compiles, then build making sure everything builds as well. Then run the program and after that set a break point on the first line of execution and step through the code to follow the logic.

Comment: @William (...continued) If you are on a mac, Linux/Unix, then you will have to make a few changes that are specific to each platform. This is built with the flag "multibyte" instead of the default "Unicode" in VS project settings.  When I first started to learn c++ this website did not exist yet, and I had to resort to a very limited resource of books and a handful of text websites from the 90s where you just read and if it didn't work, you couldn't ask questions. Being that I'm self taught, I enjoy helping out where I can to give others the advantages I didn't have.

Comment: thanks for the hell franics you code help a lot ... it even taught me more and it so happens its helping with my next assignment  XD

Answer (score 0):

for sorting on the basis of any col you can use `sort()` in `algorithm` header with your own compare function.
Define your compare function like this:

on the basis of Health:

```
bool MyCompHealth(struct charData a,struct charData b) 
{ 
    return (a.charHealth>b.charHealth);
}
```

on the basis of Exp:

```
bool MyCompExp(struct charData a,struct charData b) 
{ 
    return (a.charExp > b.charExp); 
}
```

on the basis of Name:

```
bool MyCompName(struct charData a,struct charData b) 
{ 
    int r = a.charName.compare(b.charName);
    return (r > 0);
}
```

code:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

struct charData
{
    string charName;
    float charHealth;
    int charExp;
};

bool MyCompHealth(struct charData a,struct charData b) 
{ 
    return (a.charHealth<b.charHealth);
}

//on the basis of Exp:

bool MyCompExp(struct charData a,struct charData b) 
{ 
    return (a.charExp < b.charExp); 
}

//on the basis of Name:

bool MyCompName(struct charData a,struct charData b) 
{ 
    int r = a.charName.compare(b.charName);
    return !(r > 0);
}

int main() {
    const int NUM_COLS = 3;
    int NUM_ROWS = 6;
    int charNumber = 0;
    int userInput;
    int loop = 0;
    int i,j;
    string line;

    ifstream myIn;    // Declare read file stream
    myIn.open("party.dat",ios::in); // Open file    

    struct charData charArray[NUM_ROWS];

    while( !myIn.eof() )   //taking input
    {
        for ( i = 0; i <  NUM_ROWS ; i++) 
        {
             myIn >> charArray[i].charName;    
             myIn >> charArray[i].charHealth;
             myIn >> charArray[i].charExp;       
        }    
    }
    cout<<"How you want to sort?(1:health 2:Exp 3:Name)\n";
    cin>>userInput; //input from user how he wants to sort

    if(userInput==1)
    {
        //sorting on the basis of health
        sort(charArray,charArray+NUM_ROWS,MyCompHealth);
    }
    else if(userInput==1)
    {
        //sorting on the basis of Experience
        sort(charArray,charArray+NUM_ROWS,MyCompExp);
    }
    else
    {
        //sorting on the basis of Name
        sort(charArray,charArray+NUM_ROWS,MyCompName);
    }

    //display result

        for ( i = 0; i <  NUM_ROWS ; i++) 
        {
             cout<<charArray[i].charName<<" ";    
             cout<<charArray[i].charHealth<<" ";
             cout<<charArray[i].charExp<<endl;       
        }    

    return 0;    
}
```